# Order categories by most posts

Tags: categories

How can I list the categories by most posts

News(100)
Updates(45)
Alerts(20)

and so on

Answer (score 1):

See the Codex page for [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) or [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), both accept an `orderby` argument value `count`:

```
wp_list_categories(
    array(
        'orderby' => 'count'
    )
);
```